# Submit button can not be clicked in Safari browser of Mac and iPhone

Tags: javascript, php, html

Below code is working fine in all browsers except Safari browser on mac computer and iphone. Button is displayed properly but user is not able to click on Submit button (form is not submitted when button is clicked) to place a vote in Safari browser.

Please advise what type of changes I need to make in my code so it works in Safari browser too like all other browsers.

Javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function confirm_vote()
{
    with(document.frm_vote)
    {
        if(isEmpty(trim(txt_code.value)))
        {
            alert("Captcha missing!!!");
            txt_code.select();
            txt_code.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to vote for this product?"))
        {
            if(confirm("Confirmation: Click 'Ok' to vote for this product or 'Cancel' to cancel."))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML & PHP

```
<form action="m_voteforme_p.php" method="post" id="frm_vote" name="frm_vote" onSubmit="return confirm_vote();">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr><td>Captcha:&nbsp;* <input type="text" name="txt_code">&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="./inc/get_unique_image.php" border="0"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" id="voteforme" name="voteforme" value="Vote For Me">
            <input type="hidden" name="hdn_mpkid" value="<?php print($rs_m_voteforme->fields("mpkid")); ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you check JS is working with safari? I mean to say there is any error in safari console?

Comment: This code looks too __old__ to me..

Comment: Make sure JavaScript is enable into safari browser

Comment: Might it be a z-index issue? Try css: `#voteforme{z-index:99999;}`

Comment: @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd, yes javascript is enabled and getting no error in safari console.

Comment: Just let me know, If you place `alert("Ok")` before `with()`. Is that alert you OR not? If this then follow same into `with()`.

Comment: @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd, sorry but I don't get your suggestion properly. Can you please clarify it little more.

Comment: Forget it, Some times may happen safari version having JS crashing issue, Please check into other then your current safari version.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure if it goes into your `confirm_vote` after you click the submit button? I copied your code to my local file, and tried that it hit the breakpoint I set in `if(isEmpty(trim(txt_code.value)))`, which means the function is invoked, but the function `isEmpty` is missed in my code, so it can't go further.

Comment: If it can hit the breakpoint you set within your function, you can go on line by line to see which line goes wrong.